# Can the return type of a function be dependent on the contents of a string fed as input?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on writing a function that receives the name of a field and returns the data that is in that field. For example

```
GetElement("Name")
```

returns a string while

```
GetElement("Version")
```

returns a int.
These values and the expected type are stored in a map with the field being a key. There are currently 9 different data types to be returned based on field.
When the program is run it will read in an xml file containing the list of fields and values to check against. Meaning that the field isn't known at compile time.

I am using C++ 14

The code is intended to read in an xml file consisting of fields and the expected value in those fields and compare the values in the file to what the actual values are as a test. The values are stored in large struct. There exists a map which uses a string field as a key to access data and for each field contains an int used as an offset and the type of the data.

The function I'm currently using consists of

```
   enum datatype
   {
      short_t,
      int_t,
      string_t,
    };
   std::pair<void*, datatype> GetValue(std::string field)
    {
        int offset = m_fieldMap[field].offset;
        char* ptr = (char*)&data;
        ptr +=offset;
        datatype type = m_fieldMap[field].type;
        return {ptr, type};
    }
```

Later I use a switch statement to figure out what type to cast the ptr to and then do a compare.

```
bool validate(std::string value)
{
datatype type;
void* rawData;
std::tie(rawData, type) = GetValue("time")
switch(type)
{
case datatype::double:
auto* val = (double*)rawData;
return val == stod(value);
}
```

Comment: Yes: `std::variant<std::string, int> GetElement(std::string const& fieldname);`

Comment: strictly speaking no, a function can only return one type, but there are types that are unions of other types (ie they can hold values of either type)

Comment: I forgot to mention I am limited to c++15

Comment: There was no C++15, only C++14 and C++17.

Comment: C++ is statically typed, so if you know the name of a member, you should know the type. this function is operating on behalf of a client that doesn't know the type, it's a user or another program, you're going to have to ship them the data in a portable, serialized form and might as well start the serializing here and return a `string` or something else generic.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're trying to write Python style code in C++, rethink your objectives. If you write C++ code using Python idioms, you will probably wind up with code that will be slower than if you'd written it in Python. Substitute your dynamically typed language for Python if it's not Python.

Comment: I'd like to point out statically typed is not the problem here, `c#` is also statically typed but you can return `object` as you want.

Comment: maybe you can use `GetElement<Type>(string field)` instead? Btw you should also post the code **use** the GetElement methods.

Comment: @appleapple "*`c#` is also statically typed but you can return object as you want*" - that is because C# has a "rooted" type system where EVERYTHING, even fundamental types, are ultimately represented as an `object`.  That is not the case in C++.

Comment: Can't you simply always return `string` and then cast appropriately? Like `int version = std::stoi(GetElement("Version"));` If not, consider creating a structure that stores the return type (possibly as enum) and a string value, keep this ambiguous type at first and then cast when you have to. Maybe give us an example how you want to use the code later on, after all the version integer has to go somewhere.

Comment: We could also return `void*` in C++. My point is more, "If you have to do this, something probably went wrong somewhere else. Stop and rethink what brought you here." If you're taking member `frobble` which you already know is an `int`, transforming it to `string` to fit a generic function, and then transforming it back to `int`  to use it, you should be calling `int getFrobble()`.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure you're reply to me or @ RemyLebeau , anyway I agree with you as my second comment i.e. `Type GetElement<Type>(string field_name)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm just add to @ user4581301 's statement, I know it's not exactly the same in `c++` (besides you can actually use `std::any` (or `std::variant` as @ Eljay point out first) )

Comment: @appleapple more a reply to Aziuth.